# C++ template template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T = int>
struct Foo {
    T t;
    Foo() { cout << "Foo" << endl; }
};

template <typename T>
struct Baz {
    T t;
    Baz() { cout << "Baz" << endl; }
};

template <typename T>
struct Bar {
    T t;
    Bar() { cout << "Bar" << endl; }
};

template <template <typename X> class T>
struct Bar {
    T data;
    Bar() : data() { cout << "Bar" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    Bar<Foo<>> a;

    Bar<Baz<float>> b;

    Bar<int> c;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm just beginning to learn about templates. And I am really confused with template template parameters. I understand that you are passing a template as an argument. In my template class for Bar where it receives a template template argument, what does `<typename X>` represent? Is `typename X` a template parameter for `class T`?

```
template <template <typename X> class T>
struct Bar {
    T data;
    Bar() : data() { cout << "Bar" << endl; }
};
```

Also, when I call my template template argument in the main function, I get errors that there are no default constructors for Bar. Why is that?

Answer (score 3):

`typename X` is only part of the template template parameters signature, you can just aswell write `template<template<typename> class T>` (without a name for the parameter of T).

Since `T` is itself a template, you need to instantiate it before you can use it as a class. The signature tells you what the template needs to be instantiated, in this case, it needs one type name.

```
template<typename X>
struct GenericThing
{
    X data;
};

template<template<typename> class T, typename E>
struct Bar
{
    T<E> sub; // instantiate T with E
    Bar() : sub() { cout << "Bar" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    Bar<GenericThing, int> intbar;
    Bar<GenericThing, float> floatbar;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

template template parameters allow you pass templates to other templates.
They are not concrete types and need to be parameterised order to instaciate them.

> In my template class for Bar where it receives a template template
>   argument, what does `<typename X>` represent?

[From the standard [basic.scope.temp]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.temp);

> The declarative region of the name of a template parameter of a
>   template template-parameter is the smallest template-parameter-list in
>   which the name was introduced.

This basically says the name is only available within the that template template's parameters list.
For many cases it is sufficient to just put `typename` without a name for a template template parameter, but names may serve to document your code.

However an example of when it is useful to give it a name is if another non type template parameter depends on it.
For [example](https://ideone.com/9gpxUH), `template <template <typename X, X> typename Y>`.

With respect too your sample code, you have two problems with the second declaration of Bar. First is that Bar  has already been declared to accept a type, not a template.
Your second declaration conflicts as it is declared to accept a template.

What you require here is a specialization of Bar, where the specialization resolves to a single Type, matching the primary template.
For instance,

```
template <template <typename> class T,typename Y>
struct Bar<T<Y>> {
    T<Y> data;
    Bar() : data() { cout << "Bar" << endl; }
};
```

The important thing to notice here is that the template parameters in the specialization can be whatever you need. It is the part after `struct Bar` that must match the primary template. All of the parameters in the specialization will be deduced from the type passed as the template parameter to your instantiation of Bar.

Your second problem is that you declare a member of Bar to be of type T. T is a template in the second case, and you cannot instantiate a template
without parameterising it.

Here is a working example of your code with the specialization of Bar.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T = int>
struct Foo {
    T t;
    Foo() { cout << "Foo" << endl; }
};

template <typename T>
struct Baz {
    T t;
    Baz() { cout << "Baz" << endl; }
};

template <typename T>
struct Bar {
    T t;
    Bar() { cout << "Bar" << endl; }
};



template <template <typename > class T,class Y>
struct Bar<T<Y>> 
{
    T<Y> data;
    Bar() : data() { cout << "Bar Specialization" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    Bar<Foo<>> a; //matches the specialization with T = template<typename> Foo and Y=int

    Bar<Baz<float>> b; //matches the specialization with T = template<typename> Baz and Y=float

    Bar<int> c; //matches the primary template with T=int

    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/V6LwCp)

Answer (score -1):

```
template <typename T>
void func_template(T& con) {
    for (const auto& c : con)
        std::cout << c << std::endl;
}

/*
        Nested Templates
        template <
            template < 
                // # of type args that will be included in the nested template
                typename,
                ...
            >
            // # of different types yo
            typename T1,
            ...
            typename TN
        >
    */

template <template<typename, typename> typename V, typename T>
void func_template3(V<T, std::allocator<T>>& vec) {
    for (const auto& elem : vec)
        std::cout << elem << std::endl;
}

template <template<typename, typename, typename, typename> typename M, typename T1, typename T2>
void func_template4(M<T1, T2, std::less<T1>, std::allocator<std::pair<const T1, T2>>> & dict) {
    for (const auto& pair : dict)
        std::cout << pair.first << " " << pair.second << std::endl;
}
```

I just learned C++ a month ago, so please bear with me. The above is the way I personally look at it. the func_template3 and func_template4 provides an example of a template printing vector and map containing any type. I find that paying attention to VS "No instance of function template 'XXXX' matches the argument list error" very useful in trying to determine the composition of built-in types for the data structure that you should include in the template.

For example:

Prior to implementing to func_template4, I used an std::map variable as an argument for func_template3, which then VS prompted me with the following error
[image]

So when I was implementing funct_template4, I basically used the *"arguments types are:(..."* part of the error to guide me on what other built-in types should be included.

I've heard arguments that implementing nested templates are typically unnecessary, since it could have been achieved via func_template1; however, I somewhat disagree because the code that you would write in func_template1 actually depend largely on what data structure you intend to use the template with. Just my 2 cents from a C++ noob.